# Get all data that I own (Firebase/Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a video & chat app.
How to get all the messages where the uid field is the users uid/email (picture 1)
Kind Regards,
Matthew

[View the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo2t2.png)

Comment: The query constraint would be `where('uid', '==', 'penson.mathys@gmail.com')`. Does that help? If not, what's the problem you're getting stuck on?

Comment: I didn't solve my issue. [My code](https://imgur.com/a/DuVY2PZ)

Comment: Instead of showing your code in a linked image, edit your question (there's a link. right under it) to show it as text in the question itself. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- I'd also recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following that guidance increases the chances someone here can help.